# Qsub: More than one host group

Tags: qsub

Is it possible to specify more than one host group in a call to qsub?

The specifications state that you can specify the host group with this syntax:

`-q long.q@@long.hgc` (if long.hgc is a host group)

But I would like to know whether it is possible to specify more than one host group. There is nothing about that in the manual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone is curious about this, the answer was really straightforward:

`-q long.q@@long.hgc,long.q@@long.hgd`  (if long.hgc and long.hgd are two host groups)